# How to insert a Slash in between a number in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a date like this:-
20091023
i have to convert it to a suitable format so that i can insert it into the database.For this firstly i have to convert it to 2009/10/23.How can i do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DateTime
    .ParseExact("20091023", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert the date into a database, then don't convert to a different string: convert it to a DateTime value (using ParseExact or TryParseExact). Then use a parameter (of a date type) in the query to use this value in the database.